# How to fix INVALIDTAGNAME error of NPM install?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, nvm

I have recently updated node from 14 to 16 and started getting INVALIDTAG error on `npm install`.

Details error log here:
[image]

Comment: How about it;
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67245896/code-einvalidtagname-npm-err-invalid-tag-name-16-0-0-tags-may-not-have-an