# Error: Cannot find module Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry nuxtjs error on npm run dev

Tags: node.js, nuxt.js

Cannot find module Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry nuxtjs error on npm run dev

FATAL  Cannot find module '/root/html/node_modules/iconv-lite/lib/index.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry

```
  at tryPackage (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:353:19)
  at Function.Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:566:18)
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:919:27)
  at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:19)
  at p (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:52925)
  at g (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:54200)
  at node_modules/external-editor/main/index.js:12:20
  at g (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:55111)
  at node_modules/inquirer/lib/prompts/editor.js:7:17
  at g (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:55111)
```

Comment: Hi, could you please give us more context here?

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Answer (score 5):

I got a similar error and fixed it by deleting node_modules and package-lock.json files and then run "npm install" to install dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

Following step should help

1. Delete the `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`
2. Run `npm install`

Comment: Deleting the lock file shouldn't be promoted. It can lead to accidental upgrade of packages and thus can potential break your project.

Comment: @LeapHawk I believe you can use "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" to fix any issues on packages. [more on peer dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Comment: @LeapHawk If you're afraid to delete the `package-lock.json` you should then fix the version in the `package.json` file, so instead of `^1.0.0` use `1.0.0` and then you can safely remove the `package-lock.json` file, so this answer do make sense

Answer (score 0):

If you use typescript, you should install ts-node and run build to compile typescript to javascript.