# Angular Project run fail, after clone github

Tags: angular, npm, node-modules, npm-install, npm-start

After successfully Clone Angular Project from GitHub, using git clone ---link. Then when I run **"npm install"** I found those errors.[image]

and When I run **"ng serve"** I found another error like this image[image]

Comment: can you share project's github link I can try it on my computer

Comment: Which version of angular and npm/node are you using..? Check the GitHub link project angular and npm version. 

Try to install the same version of angular and node which used in the Github project.

Comment: could you please replace the pictures with text copies of your errors?
People prefer to copy the text from questions/answer... (don't you prefer it yourself?)

Comment: sorry to say, this git repo is private repo. actually, it's a personal project, so I can't share my git repo.

Answer (score 1):

I will guess this is an old repo, and you have decided to update npm itself recently on your local env...

run (as per your error message)

```
npm i --legacy-peer-deps
```

npm v8+ has updated the version of the package-lock.json, and old repos have many old dependencies which might not be compatible with this update. When you run npm with `--legacy-peer-deps` [it uses the old ways](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869/4604645)...

Comment: Sorry, when i run this command, i found another problem, like npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: That is a problem between your local network and the site https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript ... Your firewall or something else might be blocking it. Make sure it works on your browser before proceeding