# I can't run "npm install" after clone from github (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, runtime-error

I cloned a repository from github and after that i tried to run "npm install" but i keep getting this error:

[image]

the project is still under development, so do i need to install or add anything in order to run it?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)? Run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Comment: The error message says "retry this command ..." did you try that? Also, please don't post images of text.

Answer (score 1):

Try following command:

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps

It tells NPM to ignore peer deps and proceed with the installation anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh