# Created image with use-react-screenshot is incorrectly rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, screenshot

I'm using `use-react-screenshot` to take a screenshot of a specific dom element, but the image gets weird, it looks like it partially renders the dom element

[image: This is the generated image after running the takescreenshot function]

I'm using the sample code in `create-react-app`

```js
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import { createRef } from "react";
import { useScreenshot, createFileName } from "use-react-screenshot";

function App() {
    const ref = createRef(null);
    const [image, takeScreenShot] = useScreenshot({
        type: "image/jpeg",
        quality: 1.0,
    });

    const download = (image, { name = "img", extension = "jpg" } = {}) => {
        const a = document.createElement("a");
        a.href = image;
        a.download = createFileName(extension, name);
        a.click();
    };

    const downloadScreenshot = () => takeScreenShot(ref.current).then(download);

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <header className="App-header">
                <button onClick={downloadScreenshot}>
                    Download screenshot
                </button>
                <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" ref={ref} />
            </header>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

A [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-curie-qbh8si?file=/src/App.js) to play around with it

I'm not sure if it's related to html2canvas as a peerDependency. And wherever I put the `ref` to, the same error happens

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On [github](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20%20svg%20zoom) there were a lot of issues related with SVG not downloading properly with html2canvas. I suspect these to be the issues. Solutions / [workaround](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/1441#issuecomment-380080642) provided by users includes code modifications to the internal code. This is again hard to maintain further along. Also Firefox showed blank image when downloaded.

My best solution would be to use an alternative library like [html-to-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-image). Within a few minutes everything seems to be working with this. (Even Firefox)

```
import * as htmlToImage from "html-to-image";
...
  const takeScreenShot = async (node) => {
    const dataURI = await htmlToImage.toJpeg(node);
    return dataURI;
  };

  const download = (image, { name = "img", extension = "jpg" } = {}) => {
    const a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = image;
    a.download = createFileName(extension, name);
    a.click();
  };

  const downloadScreenshot = () => takeScreenShot(ref.current).then(download);
...
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-carlos-rf55oe)

Now this might not be the best solution, but it is the best alternative working solution right now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to work better however, when I do it on my personal project, the structure gets messed up, like if there were random values in absolute position (I'm screenshooting text), and it has some webpack errors when compiling.. but I'll take a look at it and see how can I workaround it

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Badal Saibo it works as expected, would be great if you can also add implementation of `createFileName` in your solution. Since now as we're using `html-to-image` it makes no sense to download the whole `use-react-screenshot` just to use `createFileName` from it. From their github page I found the implementation of it https://github.com/vre2h/use-react-screenshot/blob/17ab790b826a95382603a2c7d1b303de4a6cb97b/src/index.js#L70

Answer (score 1):

After some research, it seems that there's an incompatibility with React V17, as it doesn't install `html2canvas` as a peerDependency like it used to do it in React V16. So, it's a [bug](https://github.com/vre2h/use-react-screenshot/issues/6).

The workaround of it is adding `html2canvas` as a peer dependency using the [legacy flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869/17311782) in the terminal

```
npm add html2canvas --legacy-peer-deps
```

After doing that, I can take screenshots