# React Native Console Problems "Npm ERR"

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, compiler-errors, expo

Does anyone know how to resolve these console errors? I don't know if this could be generating conflicts in my code. I did an update on react version and then got some inconsistencies in the application. I cleared the NPM cache, but it didn't work in a way.

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.3.0" from @callstack/react-theme-provider@3.0.8
npm ERR!   node_modules/@callstack/react-theme-provider
npm ERR!     @callstack/react-theme-provider@"^3.0.7" from react-native-paper@4.12.5
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-paper
npm ERR!       react-native-paper@"^4.12.5" from the root project        
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.0" from @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.11
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/masked-view
npm ERR!     peer @react-native-community/masked-view@">=0.1.0" from react-navigation-stack@2.10.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-navigation-stack
npm ERR!       react-navigation-stack@"^2.10.4" from the root project    
npm ERR!   32 more (@react-navigation/bottom-tabs, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-webview-modal/node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!     peer react-native-web@"*" from react-native-web-webview@1.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-webview-modal/node_modules/react-native-web-webview
npm ERR!       react-native-web-webview@"1.0.1" from react-native-webview-modal@0.0.1-alpha.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-native-webview-modal
npm ERR!   peer react-dom@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@5.3.6       
npm ERR!   node_modules/styled-components
npm ERR!     peer styled-components@">= 2" from babel-plugin-styled-components@2.0.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/babel-plugin-styled-components
npm ERR!       babel-plugin-styled-components@">= 1.12.0" from styled-components@5.3.6
npm ERR!     1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.2.0" from react-dom@18.2.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^17.0.2 || ^18.0.0" from react-native-web@0.18.10
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-native-webview-modal/node_modules/react-native-web
npm ERR!       peer react-native-web@"*" from react-native-web-webview@1.0.1
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-native-webview-modal/node_modules/react-native-web-webview
npm ERR!         react-native-web-webview@"1.0.1" from react-native-webview-modal@0.0.1-alpha.7
npm ERR!         node_modules/react-native-webview-modal
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@">= 16.8.0" from styled-components@5.3.6     
npm ERR!     node_modules/styled-components
npm ERR!       peer styled-components@">= 2" from babel-plugin-styled-components@2.0.7
npm ERR!       node_modules/babel-plugin-styled-components
npm ERR!         babel-plugin-styled-components@">= 1.12.0" from styled-components@5.3.6
npm ERR!       1 more (the root project)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
xt for a full report.
```

Does anyone know how to resolve these console errors? I don't know if this could be generating conflicts in my code. I did an update on react version and then got some inconsistencies in the application. I cleared the NPM cache, but it didn't work in a way.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This worked for me.

check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582397/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-while-installing-a-pacakge) for more information