# npm ERR! code ERESOLVE | npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I've the steps on these two threads, but to no avail.

[ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree while installing a pacakge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582397/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-while-installing-a-pacakge)
[Unable to resolve dependency tree error when installing npm packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64573177/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-error-when-installing-npm-packages?rq=1)

It's still giving me the same error on Heroku:

```
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: @solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui@0.13.1
       npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.0.26
       npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
       npm ERR!   dev @types/react@"^18.0.17" from the root project
       npm ERR!   @types/react@"*" from @types/hoist-non-react-statics@3.3.1
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@types/hoist-non-react-statics
       npm ERR!     @types/hoist-non-react-statics@"*" from @types/styled-components@5.1.26
       npm ERR!     node_modules/@types/styled-components
       npm ERR!       dev @types/styled-components@"^5.1.15" from the root project
       npm ERR!   3 more (@types/react-slick, ...)
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.1" from @solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui@0.13.1
       npm ERR! node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui
       npm ERR!   @solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui@"^0.13.1" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.52
       npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
       npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/core
       npm ERR!     peer @material-ui/core@"^4.12.1" from @solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui@0.13.1
       npm ERR!     node_modules/@solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui
       npm ERR!       @solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui@"^0.13.1" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! See /tmp/npmcache.jlWS6/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.jlWS6/_logs/2022-12-07T22_37_42_614Z-debug-0.log
```

Here's by `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "qtbotz-landing",
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "next lint",
    "lint:es": "eslint --ext .ts,.tsx .",
    "lint:fix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.tsx .",
    "dev": "open http://localhost:1337 && next dev -p 1337",
    "start": "next start",
    "build": "next build",
    "clear-all": "rm -rf .next _static node_modules",
    "re-start": "rm -rf .next _static node_modules && yarn install && yarn dev",
    "re-build": "rm -rf .next _static node_modules && yarn install && yarn build",
    "analyze": "ANALYZE=true next build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.0",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^12.0.2",
    "@next/eslint-plugin-next": "^12.0.4",
    "@project-serum/anchor": "^0.18.2",
    "@solana/spl-token": "^0.1.8",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.7.0",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-material-ui": "^0.13.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.13.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.6.1",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.11.3",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.27.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.8",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "locomotive-scroll": "^4.1.4",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "next": "^12.0.2",
    "next-compose-plugins": "^2.2.1",
    "next-seo": "^4.28.1",
    "next-transpile-modules": "^9.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-accessible-accordion": "^4.0.0",
    "react-awesome-reveal": "^4.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-locomotive-scroll": "^0.2.2",
    "react-marquee-slider": "^1.1.5",
    "react-slick": "^0.29.0",
    "react-star-sky": "^1.0.3",
    "react-starfield-animation": "^1.0.1",
    "shooting-stars": "^0.0.6",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "smooth-scrollbar": "^8.7.5",
    "smooth-scrollbar-react": "^2.3.0",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "styled-jsx-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.6",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.9",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.17",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.10",
    "@types/react-vertical-timeline-component": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.15",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.4.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.4.0",
    "eslint": "<8.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^15.0.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "^16.0.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^12.0.2",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.27.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-unused-imports": "^2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^12.0.3",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "postcss": "^8.3.11",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.2"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I've attempted to fix the problem by removing the node modules and the package.json, but every time I push to Heroku, the problem still arises.

It might be peer dependency issue, or an NPM issue but I wouldn't know where to start.

Thanks again, and let me know if you have any questions.