# Something wrong in laravel 9 and react

Tags: reactjs, vite, laravel-9

I downloaded laravel 9. But new version of laravel is using vite instead of webpack.

```
composer require laravel/ui
php artisan ui react
```

this command is working fine. But `npm install` command not working

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-react@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-react@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

After this error, I found some solution from stackoverflow here is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71582397/eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-while-installing-a-pacakge)

So, I installed this command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`
this is working fine.

Then I using this `@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])` in my view.
But my view gives me this error:

```
Uncaught Error: @vitejs/plugin-react can't detect preamble. Something is wrong. See https://github.com/vitejs/vite-plugin-react/pull/11#discussion_r430879201
at Example.jsx?t=1674104015528:6:11
```

This is my screenshot
[image]

How to solve it? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install react plugin and call the @viteReactRefresh directive in your blade,

For example:

install react plugin : `npm install --save-dev @vitejs/plugin-react`
then call @viteReactRefresh in your blade

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this wasn't in the documentation. But this is what I have in my app.blade.php file, also note to rename app.js to app.jsx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />
    @viteReactRefresh
    @vite('resources/js/app.jsx')
    @inertiaHead
  </head>
  <body>
    @inertia
  </body>
</html>
```

In addition to this, I had to do the following as we for client side setup in addition to their instructions:

1. npm install react react-dom
2. npm install @vitejs/plugin-react
3. Rename app.js to app.jsx
4. In vite.config.js, add in the react plugin.  This is what my vite.config.js looked like:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'; //added react plugin

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.jsx'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        react(),  //added react plugin
    ],
});
```