# Material UI installation doesn't work with React 18

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to install Material UI and icons with my React 18.0 project but I can't. The project has been created using the latest create-react-app
`npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons`

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   peer @material-ui/core@"^4.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.2
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

i deleted npm-cache folder and re install it
still doesn't work

Comment: Currently that doesn't support React 18, per the error.

Comment: Give a try with yarn add, also are you install MUI version < 5

Answer (score 80):

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps
npm install @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps
```

> Github Issue : https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/32074

Comment: Worked like a charm. What hides behind the --legacy-peer-deps command?

Comment: "--legacy-peer-deps restores peerDependency installation behavior from NPM v4 thru v6 One way of thinking of this flag is that it isn't doing something new; rather it's telling NPM not to do something new, since NPM v7 now installs peerDependencies by default." source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869

Comment: You can do this locally but it will create issues on live environment

Answer (score 11):

#### You can use **Materal UI v5** for reactjs **18**

`https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/`

OR

There is another way to make MUI work with Reactjs is to degrade the version of react to 17.

You just need to degrade
react version and react-dom version to 17 to make it work.

Check your package.json file there you will find react and react-dom version to 18 you have to degrade the version to make mui v4 work with Reactjs.

Use --force flag while degrading to version 17

OR
if you don't want to degrade your react 18 to 17 then follow the below instruction.

For react >= 17.0.0 and react-dom >= 17.0.0 Use MUI v5.

If you are using react version greater than 17 you must install Material UI (version) v5.

Note: if anyhow MUI v5 does not work with react@17.0.x then install MUI (version) v4.

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

AND

For react >= 16.8.0 and react-dom >= 16.8.0 then use this.

```
// with npm
npm install @material-ui/core

// with yarn
yarn add @material-ui/core
```

Comment: refer to MUI docs v4 and v5 [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)

Answer (score 7):

```
npm i @material-ui/core --legacy-peer-deps
```

Actual for 2022.04.24:

- material-ui/core v4.12.4
- react v18.0.0

Comment: How is this any different from the other answers already posted?

Answer (score 5):

Install it with `npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --force`

Answer (score 4):

This is MUI's problem with the new version of react. They are working to release a new version of Material UI. in the meantime we can solve this problem by using --legacy-peer-deps.

This is how: https://namespaceit.com/blog/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled --legacy-peer-deps
npm install @mui/icons-material --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use the new version of material UI with react 18

To install the new version with the following command:

```
// with npm
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

// with yarn
yarn add @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Answer (score 3):

I used with the `--force` flag and it worked for me

`npm install @material-ui/core`

Answer (score 1):

Use this link: https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/ To find the Material UI version for react 18
Installation: npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34135517)

Answer (score 1):

[@material-ui/core@4.12.3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/core) is incompatible with `React 18.x` and it has been deprecated. Please use [MUI v5](https://mui.com/)

Let's check the peer dependencies of MUI v4:

```
$ npm view @material-ui/core@4.12.3 peerDependencies
{
  '@types/react': '^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0',
  react: '^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0',
  'react-dom': '^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0'
}
```

As you can see, MUI v4 work with `React ^16.8.0` or `React ^17.0.0`. But in your project, the React version is `^18.0.0` which is incompatible.

Related issue:

- https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/33216
- [[core] Update peer deps to support React 18](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/pull/32063)

The MUI v5.6.0 started to support React 18, the latest version is `5.13.6`(until 2023.7.4). So you can install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

`@material-ui/core` will not work in React 18.

Instead you can use `@mui/material`

For instance, you can convert your package names in React 18.

```
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import SendIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Send';
```

to

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Paper from '@mui/material/Paper';
import SendIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Send';
```

It is working fine in React 18 environment. Don't use *`--legacy-peer-deps`*

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding an `overrides` line to my `package.json` file, which means you don't have to write `--force` every time you update:

```json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.14.13",
        "@mui/material": "^5.14.13",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.14.13",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
    }
    "overrides": {
        "@mui/styles": {
            "react": ">=18.2.0",
            "react-dom": ">=18.2.0"
        }
    }
}
```