# When I try to install material ui icon dependency face this error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

```
npm i @material-ui/icons
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: my-app@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.1.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.1.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.1.0" from react-dom@18.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-dom
npm ERR!     peer react-dom@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.1.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm ERR!       @testing-library/react@"^13.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   1 more (react-scripts)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @material-ui/icons@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/icons@4.11.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/icons
npm ERR!     @material-ui/icons@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Vikash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:npm ERR!     C:\Users\Vikash\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-03T21_09_36_618Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\Vikash\Desktop\personal portfolio\my-app>
```

Comment: Please note https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/3001761. Also did you read the error message?

Comment: The error is because you are using the newest version of React (18.0) which is not yet supported by Material UI. See more here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713111/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to install MUI v5 with React 18.1.0

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

Follow [MUI Documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/getting-started/installation/)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below

```
npm i @material-ui/icons --legacy-peer-deps
```

Then it happens new errors, I tried to upgrade `"@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4"` and it works.