# NPM error when installing dependency on React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i cant install some dependencies . this is a screenshot of what they usually tell me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utAnc.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713111/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18

Comment: Please, don't attach a screenshot of your error, you could have posted the code you are running and the error you are getting correctly formatted, this way, another user getting the same error message could get the problem solved without needing to post a new question. This link provides some information about how to format your questions (and answers) so they are readable: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

that's because of version of dependencies,
better way is to install campatable versions but if you really want to install them you can use --force in command.
sth like this :

```
npm i --force package_name
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to install material ui core library separately, but it comes with material ui itself, so either you have to remove material ui core from dependency or use `--force` with `npm` command.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the installation command with the `–force` command and your error will be solved  like this :

```
npm install <your package> –force
```

if it did not work try  :

```
npm install <your package> --legacy-peer-deps
```