# How to Install Material UI styles

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to install Material Ui styles in my application but i keep getting an error:

[image]

Comment: You need to downgrade your react version to 17

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MUI installation doesn't work with React 18](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71713111/mui-installation-doesnt-work-with-react-18)