# npx create-react-app has suddenly stopped working

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I've been running 'npx create-react-app' for my projects for the last few months however today when I tried to run the command to create a new project I got this error:

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRlju.png)

I've tried clearing my cache, running 'npx create-react-app@latest' with no luck so far.

Comment: Check out this answer. It describes indetail. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Answer (score 0):

Try clearing `legacy-peer-deps`

```
npx create-react-app myapp --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried creating a new React project on React 18 with create-react-app and ran into this.

The following worked for me:

Open the project via vs code (or any other terminal) and run the npm install command again to install the dependencies:

```
npm install
```

If after running the above command, the same error still persists, try:

```
 npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug, we have to wait until the next update but you can try to install it and remove the node_module and after change the react-dom and react to a lower version like 17.0.2

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).