# How to get npm to install a single package?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have downloaded an npm project, and `npm install` fails with a bunch of dependency errors. In an attempt to find the problem, I've tried installing each dependency individually with, e.g., `npm install react`, but the command ignores the single argument and instead gives the same errors as trying to install the entire project.  In desperation I tried the example from https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install: 'npm install sax`, where sax has nothing to do with the project, and it still fails.

package.json is:

```json
{
  "name": "graphiql-explorer-example",
  "homepage": "https://onegraph.github.io/graphiql-explorer-example",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "graphiql": "^0.12.0",
    "graphql": "^14.1.1",
    "graphiql-explorer": "^0.6.2",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "flow": "flow",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "predeploy": "yarn build",
    "prettier": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\" \"docs/**/*.md\" README.md"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "flow-bin": "^0.91.0",
    "gh-pages": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "description": "Example usage of [OneGraph](https://www.onegraph.com)'s open source [GraphiQL explorer](https://github.com/OneGraph/graphiql-explorer).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/OneGraph/graphiql-explorer-example.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/OneGraph/graphiql-explorer-example/issues"
  }
}
```

The error messages are:

```
   > npm install react

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: graphiql-explorer-example@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: graphql@14.1.1
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^14.1.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^0.6.0 || ^0.7.0 || ^0.8.0-b || ^0.9.0 || ^0.10.0 || ^0.11.0 || ^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0" from graphiql@0.12.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphiql
npm ERR!   graphiql@"^0.12.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

The log file (excluding a pile of "timing" and "silly" messages) is:

```
1 info using npm@8.8.0
2 info using node@v16.14.2

22 verbose title npm install sax
23 verbose argv "install" "sax"

41 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graphiql 144ms (cache revalidated)

43 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/graphql 47ms (cache revalidated)

47 verbose stack Error: unable to resolve dependency tree
```

As you can see, npm parses the "sax" argument correctly on line 23, but then ignores it and tries to install graphiql instead.

How can I get npm to install a single package, such as the latest version of react, instead of trying to install all of the dependencies for graphiql-explorer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem here is the [peer dependencies](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/) of "sax"

there are some ways to avoid checking peer dependency.

**Method 1**

```
npm install <package name> --force
```

or

```
npm install <package name> --legacy-peer-deps
```

but it is not recommended,

Adding --legacy-peer-deps to your npm installation will bypass peerDependency auto-installation, but this may result in conflicts due to potentially breaking changes

try to resove conflicts manually, by getting the peer dependency details using

```
npm info name-of-module peerDependencies
```

for more information refer: [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Comment: Thanks for the information pointers - understanding the cause of a problem is essential.

Answer (score 0):

There is a fix for running the `npm install` command.

```
$ npm install
```

---

According to your error message when running the installation command:

```
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

It states that some dependencies are incompatible with others. To fix this, you need to run the installation command with the following flag.

```
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

This should resolve the issue of the dependencies being incompatible with each other.

---

In conclusion, the issue was that the dependencies were incompatible with each other. However, there is a fix!

```
$ npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```