# How to install react navigation?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I'm a beginner in coding which means i follow tutorials from youtube. The project that i'm making uses            **react-navigation/native**, but when i tried to install it, it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! Found: react-native-safe-area-context@4.2.5
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   react-native-safe-area-context@"^4.2.5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-elements     
npm ERR!   react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native-safe-area-context@3.4.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native-safe-area-context
npm ERR!   peer react-native-safe-area-context@"^3.1.9" from react-native-elements@3.4.2        
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native-elements   
npm ERR!     react-native-elements@"^3.4.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.     
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full r
eport.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ps3pl\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-05-29T06_56_49_981Z-d
ebug-0.log
```

I am building using EXPO
This is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "uber-clone",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "expo": "~45.0.0",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.3.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.2.5",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.1.0",
    "react-native-web": "0.17.7",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "tailwind-react-native-classnames": "^1.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the flag `--legacy-peer-deps`.

```
npm install @react-navigation/native --legacy-peer-deps
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem is almost similar to [How to get npm to install a single package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72064881/how-to-get-npm-to-install-a-single-package/72065689#72065689)

read the answer carefully.

**solution:**

try to resolve the issue with correct package version as the error message suggested.

if you couldn't do it use

```
npm install @react-navigation/native --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
npm install @react-navigation/native --force
```

Be sure you may get conflict issues while developing.