# material ui is showing error while installing

Tags: reactjs

npm install @material-ui/core is showing error while installing. I used other commands also to install but still showing error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewujl.png)

Answer (score 0):

`material-ui` uses `react` versions 16 or 17 as the peer dependencies even if you've `react` version 18 in your root project. You can run `npm install` with following configuration in order to avoid peer dependency auto installation and do the installation the way it was with `npm` v4 through v6.

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm install
```

Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh) for more info. on `--legacy-peer-deps` flag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npm i
```

Comment: `npm i` is the same as `npm install` since `i` [is an alias](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) of `install`. As such, this answer duplicates [the earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73316081/1364007) and should be deleted.