# After running all the installations I'm getting an error, how to fix it?

Tags: reactjs, npm

***The only thing done before this is `npx create-react-app ./`***

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react
```

***after running this I am getting the next error:***

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: travel_advisor@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/core@4.12.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/core
npm ERR!   @material-ui/core@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-27T18_43_01_094Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\travel_advisor>
```

***I have tried updating npm with `npm install -g npm` but it doesn't change anything***

Comment: Looks like downgrading it to npm6 with `npm install -g npm@6` works, is that a good way?

Comment: try ```npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react --legacy-peer-deps```

Comment: after downgrading and trying again, here's what I got:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
npm install @material-ui/core @material-ui/icons @material-ui/lab @react-google-maps/api axios google-map-react --force
```

or try to install packages once at a time. That way you can understand which one causing problem with *peer dependency*

Answer (score 0):

`@material-ui/core` depends on react ^16.8 or ^17.0, you installed react 18.2

Try the new material-ui v5:

```
npm install @mui/material @emotion/react @emotion/styled
```

https://mui.com/