# Unable to install ng-recaptcha3 in angular 14 project - npm ERR! code ERESOLVE

Tags: angular

I have an old angular project (v12) and I need to migrate it to latest (v14). So, I followed the angular update guide and ran the `ng update @angular/core@13 @angular/cli@13` and then `ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14` commands. Now, I am trying to install ng-recaptcha3. However, I get these errors on console/terminal, stopping me from adding ng-recaptcha3.

```
me@computer:/home/me/projects/active/project1/repo1$ npm i ng-recaptcha3
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: repo1@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@14.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^14.0.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^8.2.14" from ng-recaptcha3@1.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/ng-recaptcha3
npm ERR!   ng-recaptcha3@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /home/me/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/.npm/_logs/2022-08-28T15_48_12_688Z-debug-0.log
```

This is my `ng version` output

```
Angular CLI: 14.2.1
Node: 18.2.0 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 8.18.0 
OS: linux x64

Angular: 14.2.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1402.1
@angular-devkit/build-angular   14.2.1
@angular-devkit/core            14.2.1
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.1
@angular/cli                    14.2.1
@angular/fire                   7.4.1
@schematics/angular             14.2.1
rxjs                            7.5.6
typescript                      4.7.4
    
Warning: The current version of Node (18.2.0) is not supported by Angular.
```

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "repo1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^7.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^14.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^14.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~14.2.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^14.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.3.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.0.0",
    "typescript": "~4.7.2"
  }
}
```

I even tried to create a new angular project using `ng new repo1` and tried to install the ng-recaptcha3, ended up with same result - `npm ERR! code ERESOLVE`
Could any one please help me understand what am I doing wrong or what steps to be taken to integrate ng-recaptcha3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is just an npm safety thing now a days. You need to run `npm i ng-recaptcha3 --legacy-peer-deps` and I believe it should work.

NPM has stopped auto installing legacy packages automatically so that it forces you to know the "risk" you're taking. Nothing to really concern yourself with here

Comment: I don't know what risk I am taking. However, `--legacy-peer-deps` worked. Moving on

Comment: here’s a post detailing it a bit more https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869/15492085

Comment: actually new version of ng-recaptcha3@1.4.0 is available where the peer dependency isue was fixed