# npm i react-google-login is not able to install

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-google-login

I am trying to install the package "react-google-login" in my project for user authentication.
Here is the error code :

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: client@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16 || ^17" from react-google-login@5.2.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react-google-login
npm ERR!   react-google-login@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\prajw\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-08-30T16_30_08_237Z-debug-0.log
```

I think there is some error with version of react

Answer (score 2):

I think this might fix your issues. try this

> npm i react-google-login --legacy-peer-deps

What does this do? it ignores old dependencies for this package.
You can learn more about legacy peer deps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)