# Material UI causing npm installation error : ERESOLVE could not resolve

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Getting ERESOLVE error when trying to `npm i`
[image]

Here is the Package.json file

```
{
  "name": "client-forntend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/data-grid": "^4.0.0-alpha.26",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.4",
    "@material-ui/system": "^4.11.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "material-ui-chip-input": "^1.1.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-emoji": "^0.5.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-file-base64": "^1.0.3",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This project was untouched for the last one year. Now its not running.
So, i have tried this`rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` and re-installed node_modules didn't worked.
now it's not installing packages.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: im assuming you have already tried installing with legacy peer deps?

Comment: @Fiehra yes, I have done this already. no luck

Comment: @Sajib have you also tried running npm I --force?

Comment: @g0rb yes mate. I have tried this too, and maybe all the existing methods from StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sajib Could you show us the errors you get when running `npm i --force`? Also have you tried removing node_modules and package-lock.json then running `npm i --force`?

Comment: I ran into this a while back.  If you have updated node and npm since the last time you ran this project, you may see these dependency errors.  Ever since Node v7, it installs dependencies in a more strict mode.  `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` will make it act like it did pre-version 7.  A better explanation here>>> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh

Comment: @g0rb it shows something like this, ```node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:494
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/tokenize' is not defined by "exports" in ```  And after installing legacy-peers, if I run, then it show's like this, ```node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:949
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'webpack'```

Comment: Delete `material-ui-chip-input` dependency and install again.

Comment: @Sajib, is there a .nvm file in your project? Do you know which version of node you were using when you originally installed this project? It may be an issue with your node version.

Comment: @g0rb no, there isn't any .nvm file. I was using a different version of Node. Maybe I was using node version 16, and now I am using node version 18... Now, I am trying to use all the newer versions of the dependency which are compatible with the latest react and node versions. hope so this will work.

Comment: @Sajib, alright keep us updated.

Answer (score 1):

Material ui has changed their brand name to mui so you should download the new packages. As for material ui chip input when I removed the package the error was gone.