# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^16.6.0" from @hmscore/react-native-hms-health@6.0.0-300

Tags: reactjs, react-native, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, huawei-map-kit

[enter image description here][1]

i am trying integrate Huawei`` health
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aSVdd.png)

```
enter code here
```

npm i @hmscore/react-native-hms-health

Comment: What are you asking here? Take a look at the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and expand your question accordingly. As it is currently, it contains no question, just a statement of intent ("i am trying integrate Huawei"). You should also not post a picture of an error, but put it as text in here, as it is much easier for us to answer a question that way. Missing here is also a minimal reproducable code (which in this case would be the dependency section of your `package.json` file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the "-- legacy peer deps" tag during the installation of npm. This is a known issue of RN.

Comment: Can you please share any documented reference as well for this being a known issue?

Comment: Hi, you can take a look at this link, I hope it helps you：https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh

Comment: Thanks for the link @Shirley, I voted to close the original question as duplicate