# Error running `npm i`: Found: react@undefined

Tags: reactjs, npm, material-ui

I have a CRA project and while running `npm i` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: telo-ui@8.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react@undefined
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0" from @mui/material@5.10.8
npm ERR! node_modules/@mui/material
npm ERR!   @mui/material@"^5.10.8" from the root project
```

I understand this is an incompatibility between react and mui, but I see that MUI requires react >= 17 as a peer dependency, so I should be OK.

Here are my deps and devDeps from my `package.json` file:

```
    "dependencies": {
        "@azure/communication-calling": "^1.6.3",
        "@azure/communication-common": "^2.1.0",
        "@date-io/date-fns": "^2.16.0",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.8",
        "@mui/lab": "^1.0.0",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.6",
        "@mui/styles": "^5.10.8",
        "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.3",
        "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.5",
        "@sentry/react": "^7.14.1",
        "@sentry/tracing": "^7.14.1",
        "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
        "date-fns-tz": "^1.3.7",
        "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "final-form": "^4.20.7",
        "formik": "^2.2.9",
        "fuse.js": "^6.6.2",
        "i18next": "^21.9.2",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.5",
        "i18next-xhr-backend": "^3.2.2",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "react": "^18.2.3",
        "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1",
        "react-dates": "^21.8.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
        "react-final-form": "^6.5.9",
        "react-i18next": "^11.18.6",
        "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.4",
        "react-joyride": "^2.5.3",
        "react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
        "react-query": "^3.39.2",
        "react-redux": "^8.0.4",
        "react-resizable": "^3.0.4",
        "react-responsive-carousel": "^3.2.23",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.4.1",
        "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
        "react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.6",
        "react-table": "^7.8.0",
        "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.6",
        "ua-parser-js": "^1.0.2",
        "validate.js": "^0.13.1",
        "yup": "^0.32.11"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@commitlint/cli": "^17.1.2",
        "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^17.1.0",
        "@release-it/conventional-changelog": "^5.1.0",
        "@storybook/addon-actions": "^6.5.12",
        "@storybook/addon-links": "^6.5.12",
        "@storybook/addons": "^6.5.12",
        "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
        "@storybook/react": "^6.5.12",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^14.4.3",
        "@types/downloadjs": "^1.4.3",
        "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.5",
        "@types/jest": "^29.1.1",
        "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
        "@types/lodash": "^4.14.186",
        "@types/node": "^18.8.2",
        "@types/react": "^18.0.21",
        "@types/react-dates": "^21.8.3",
        "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.6",
        "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.5",
        "@types/react-pdf": "^5.7.2",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.24",
        "@types/react-resizable": "^3.0.3",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.3",
        "@types/react-signature-canvas": "^1.0.2",
        "@types/react-table": "^7.7.12",
        "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.36",
        "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.26",
        "@types/ua-parser-js": "^0.7.36",
        "@types/yup": "^0.29.14",
        "husky": "^8.0.1",
        "jest-environment-jsdom-sixteen": "^1.0.3",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "pretty-quick": "^3.1.3",
        "redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
        "release-it": "^15.5.0",
        "typescript": "^4.8.4"
    },
```

How can I determine what are the failing deps and how can I fix those?

Note that I just upgraded all of my deps with `ncu -u` command. I also tried to upgrade lib by lib gradually, but at a certain point I step into the same issue and I don't know how I can get rid of it.

Comment: Try to remove package-lock.json and node_modules and rerun npm i. You can also try to run npm cache clean --force

Comment: I forgot to mention that I tried those steps also. Still the issue persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things you can do:

1. remove package-lock.json and retry `npm i`
2. run `npm i` with the flag `--legacy-peer-deps`

If you are using npm >= v7, try to use `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` because, after npm v6, it tries to install peer deps automatically, but some libraries don't define peer deps versions correctly, so it fails.

If that is the case, use npm v6 or npm v7 with the flag mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I wasn't aware of that flag. I am running npm 8.19.2 and tried to run `npm i --legacy--peer-deps` as you suggested, but then I get another error:

`No matching version found for @mui/lab@^1.0.0. In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting a package version that doesn't exist.`

Comment: Oh, of course, it is self explanatory. I need to use the proper version of `@mui/lab`. I don't think I need it, so I am going to drop it

Comment: The `--legacy-peer-deps` did the trick. Also, I needed to amend a few uncorrect versions, but the error messages from `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` helped me understand which were wrong. Also, please check this other question that contains some useful information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh