# having issue deploying angular app on netlify

Tags: angular, netlify

i'm having issues deploying my angular app to netlify, the app is working perfectly on my local host but when i deploy i get the following err
can anyone help out

```
9:41:28 PM: npm WARN config     [`cacache`](http://npm.im/cacache).
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! While resolving: @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.6
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! Found: @angular/compiler@14.0.3
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   @angular/compiler@"^14.0.2" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"14.0.3" from @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@14.0.3
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@"^14.0.2" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.6" from @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.6
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.2" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.0.3
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!     dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~14.0.3" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   2 more (@angular/localize, @ngtools/webpack)
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler@14.2.6
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/compiler
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   peer @angular/compiler@"14.2.6" from @angular/compiler-cli@14.2.6
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!     @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.2" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!     peer @angular/compiler-cli@"^14.0.0" from @angular-devkit/build-angular@14.0.3
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!       dev @angular-devkit/build-angular@"~14.0.3" from the root project
9:41:29 PM: npm ERR!
9:41:29 PM: Build was terminated: Build script returned non-zero exit code: 1
9:41:29 PM: Creating deploy upload records
9:41:29 PM: Failing build: Failed to build site
Top comments (0)
```

enter image description here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use a `.npmrc` file to specify options during the install.

If you haven't already, add a `.npmrc` file to the project root with the following content:

```bash
legacy-peer-deps=true
```

For more information on what this option does, see: [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)

Comment: the deployment was successful, but when i click on the app link https://jobkonnect.netlify.app/, i'm getting a 404   error

Answer (score 0):

The npm install command fails. clean your package.json or try `npm install --force`

to clean your package.json set the same angular version to all your angular libraries.

Comment: this is on netlify oh, not on my localhost

Comment: in the build & deploy setting you can change the command line done by netlify. But if you clear your package.json it will works. to clean, remove your node_modules folder 'rm -rf node_modules'  and try reinstall with the same command line you found on netlify build setting

Comment: am i clearing the package.json file on my device or that on netlify ?

Comment: on your device. (it's work on your device but maybe you use --force to install package so you need to have a clear package.json) 

just change the  Librairies with angular in it at version 14.2.6 first

Comment: i've done that, but it still same err, i tried updating to lastest version, but it says everytin seems good

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Comment: i've added a screenshot of it to the initial post

Comment: in text to copy it

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling `node_modules` is halfway resolving the issue. The correct way is to delete `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`. Then, `npm install` again to generate a new `package-lock.json` file.

My case is upgrading Angular from 16 to 17, FYI.