# error occured when do npm install && npm run dev - Vite - Laravel UI React

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel, vite

hello everyone today i had a problem that's when i install **laravel ui with react** and pass to the step of **npm install** an error occured so below you will find the error

```
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\E495\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-01-16T08_08_36_872Z-debug-0.log
PS C:\Users\E495\Desktop\laravel-simple-crud> npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined
npm ERR! Found: vite@4.0.4
npm ERR! node_modules/vite
npm ERR!   dev vite@"^4.0.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer vite@"^3.0.0" from @vitejs/plugin-react@2.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@vitejs/plugin-react
npm ERR!   dev @vitejs/plugin-react@"^2.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\E495\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
```

so above the error and below you'll find my **package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.6",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^2.2.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.4.2",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.2",
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "bootstrap": "^5.2.3",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.6",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "sass": "^1.56.1",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^4.0.4"
    }
}
```

i try to read the error and change the **vite version to 4.0.4** but without any result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to get by this error with the following command:

```bash
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

[This previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh) goes into detail about what `--legacy-peer-deps` is doing here.

In short, `@vitejs/plugin-react` (specifically the version `2.2.0` you have as a dev dependency) has listed an older version of vite (`vite@"^3.0.0"`) as one of its **peer dependencies**, but it is finding the newer `vite@"^4.0.4"` installed. For reasons that I can't totally explain (see the linked post or Google if you're curious), NPM is not able to resolve this peer dependency conflict as it usually would for the regular dependencies and dev dependencies that we're more familiar with. `--legacy-peer-deps` gets around this by bypassing peer dependency auto-installation.

Comment: To assist those Googling with a similar problem—I had this same problem when dealing with a particular version of `@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte` that had a peer dependency issue for vite. The above command also resolve my issue.

Comment: yeah it's work! and also when use npm install --force it will work