# peer dependencies in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, npm-install

I got error regarding peer dependencies when I try to install package.json using "npm install".

[Peer Dependency error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EjWor.png)

I have learned that I can use "npm install -legacy-peer-deps" from this link [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh/75161654#75161654).

But I know that "npm install --legacy-peer-deps" ignores peer dependencies so I am looking for different solutions for this error that I attached screenshot. I have tried to define "peerDependencies" in package.json to prevent dependency error but the different versions of the same package are shown as a dependency as shown below screenshot.

[different versions of peer dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3wRA.png)

My package.json are shown as below. Would you help me about this problem? What do you suggest for peer dependency problems? When I want to add new packages to package.json, I will face the peer dependency problem again. Thanks.

```
{
  "name": "metric-tutorial",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
    "angular-material-fileupload": "^3.0.2",
    "mathjax-angular": "^1.4.2",
    "rxjs": "~7.5.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "~13.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.10.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "angular-cli-ghpages": "^1.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: [angular-material-fileupload](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-material-fileupload) is very old and doesn't support angular 13, use a different library or live with the error

Comment: When I install "npm i file-saver", I face the same error again. So is this related to angular 13?

Comment: Had you removed the `angular-material-fileupload` before installing `file-saver`?