# How can I install this dependency in angular app

Tags: angular, npm, dependencies

Working on my project using angular, wanted to install dependency, but this happened. How can I fix this? [Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Hpb0.png)

Comment: The answer is in the error. You either need to use the `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` option when installing the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Error says that ngx-simple-countdown@13.0.1 requires @angular/common version 13.3+, but your project has ~13.2.0 (updated only patch version).

So you need to install @angular/common@13.3+ version on run npm i with "--legacy-peer-deps" that will skip installing peer deps (more you can read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66620869/13360723))