# Does "react": "^18.2.0" support 'connected-react-router'?

Tags: reactjs

I am using `"react": "^18.2.0"` and trying to initialize combineReducers as below

```
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router';

const reducer = combineReducers({
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
})
```

I got this error

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'connected-react-router'
```

then I ran

```
npm install --save connected-react-router
```

npm install failed with below details

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: daf-react-ui@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.4.0 || ^17.0.0" from connected-react-router@6.9.3
npm ERR! node_modules/connected-react-router
npm ERR!   connected-react-router@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/kkpk/.npm/_logs/2023-03-02T18_30_55_591Z-eresolve-report.txt
```

is there any workaround for this conflict?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so it support v18 since its [`peerDeps`](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/package.json#L34) is

[image]

**[peerDependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh#:%7E:text=peerDependencies%3A%20A%20peer%20dependency%20is,is%20designed%20to%20work%20with.)**: A peer dependency is a specific version or set of versions of a third-party software library that a module is designed to work with.