# What is the solution to fix the version conflict in reactNative?

Tags: react-native, helper

When I run "npm start" I get this error.

```
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: use-memo-one@1.1.2
npm WARN Found: react@18.2.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"18.2.0" from the root project
npm WARN   25 more (@callstack/react-theme-provider, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from use-memo-one@1.1.2
npm WARN node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/node_modules/use-memo-one
npm WARN   use-memo-one@"1.1.2" from react-native-gifted-chat@1.1.1
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0" from use-memo-one@1.1.2
npm WARN   node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat/node_modules/use-memo-one
npm WARN     use-memo-one@"1.1.2" from react-native-gifted-chat@1.1.1
npm WARN     node_modules/react-native-gifted-chat
```

In the versioning errors I tried to update the libraries

Comment: Have you tried npm install with --legacy-peer-deps flag ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does npm install --legacy-peer-deps do exactly? When is it recommended / What's a potential use case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66239691/what-does-npm-install-legacy-peer-deps-do-exactly-when-is-it-recommended-wh)